# Switching between monitor profiles on Vista

Tags: windows-vista, multiple-monitors, display

Are there any alternatives to UltraMon when setting up shortcuts to different monitor profiles for easy switching (eg. work - triple monitor setup, home - laptop screen only)?

The only problem with Ultramon so far that it is commercial.
However, it would be interesting to explore other commercial alternatives too if no free ones available.

Answer (score 1):

the only two freeware 'alternatives i know of, are not as good as UltraMon. but have a look yourself and check their features.

[**MultiMonitor TaskBar**](http://www.mediachance.com/free/multimon.htm)

[**DisplayFusion**](http://www.binaryfortress.com/displayfusion/)

and then there is **[PowerStrip](http://entechtaiwan.com/util/ps.shtm)**, handy if you're using multiple graphics adapter (a commercial application)

Answer (score 0):

You might also have a look at [dispcalGUI](http://hoech.net/dispcalGUI/) and [Calibrize](http://www.calibrize.com/).